# Molecular knots absolute configuration

Tags: nomenclature, stereochemistry, supramolecular-chemistry

How is the absolute configuration of chiral [molecular knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_knot) determined? What rules should be applied? For centrochiral compounds, the CIP rules are applied, for axially chiral is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_chirality) and for planar chiral [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_chirality). I can't find the system for assigning R/S (or possibly some other stereodescriptors) for molecular knots, e.g  the attached knot doesn't contain an Sn improper axis, therefore it is chiral.

[image]

Comment: I edited your question to improve it, but it would be still nice if you elaborated.

Comment: This is where topology\mathematics meets chemistry and becomes fairly complex fairly quickly.  Mislow, one of the great, modern-day stereochemists, got the ball rolling.  If you google "Mislow, trefoil chirality" you'll get a number of useful links, but again, it's involved.

Comment: I've read it a bit and encountered this interesting question: could these compounds be resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nomenclature of knot-like structures is not yet developed in IUPAC, let alone their stereochemistry.

However, there are some attempts in chemistry literature to describe the knots, drawing inspiration from math [knot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory) (however, even the detection of [chiral knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_knot) is not yet completely resolved problem, apparently).

And sometimes there are contradictions. In [TAUBER, Stephen J. Absolute Configuration and Chemical Topology. *J. Res. Nat. Bur. Stand. A*, 1963, 67: 591-599.](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/67A/jresv67An6p591_A1b.pdf), you example knot's (let us just rotate him slightly in the paper plane by 60° clockwise or anticlockwise, does not matter, for "compatibility") intersection points are, according with the rule:

[image: plus minus rule scheme]

designated with plus signs at the intersection points:

[image: knot plus]

and the enantiomeric one with minuses:

[image: knot minus]

This notation is mentioned elsewhere, e.g. in [SCHILL, Gottfried. Catenanes, rotaxanes, and knots. Elsevier, 2013.](https://books.google.com/books?id=MUWf3E7EAQIC)

However, in [SAUVAGE, Jean-Pierre; DIETRICH-BUCHECKER, Christiane (ed.). *Molecular catenanes, rotaxanes and knots: a journey through the world of molecular topology.* John Wiley & Sons, 2008.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/9783527613724), in the chapter DNA Knots, your example knot is denoted in the opposite sense with minus signs,

[image]

and named "TREFOIL KNOT (−), 3<sub>1</sub><sup>−</sup>", and the opposite one as "TREFOIL KNOT (+), 3<sub>1</sub><sup>+</sup>".

Answer (score 8):

I guess that the IUPAC Gold Book rules for helicity apply here.

> The chirality of a helical, propeller or screw-shaped molecular entity. A right-handed helix is described as P (or plus), a left-handed one as M (or minus).

The above knotane is right-handed, so it should be P.

For more complex molecular knots such simple rules most likely will fail.

Comment: I agree that this system is applicable, but I would argue that the helicity here is left handed (*M*). Do you have any source applying the this system trefoil knot? Btw,  [here](https://youtu.be/5Mf0JpTI_gg?t=2m13s) is knots helicity boosted one level above :)

Comment: From both the image in the IUPAC Golden Book and from applying the right hand rule to the propeller (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) I concluded that it should be P. However, I don't know any source where the system is applied to the molecular trefoil knot. Mathematically the trefoil knots are classified the other way round. So I might be wrong.

Comment: i think it could be designated _P_ using both the knot intersection points method in my answer and [helicity nomenclature](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/stereo/FM.html#11) when focusing on fan lobes, or in opposite sense _M_ when focusing on the interior – the knot it can be threaded on the "anti-screw" (levorotatory helix)